# Receive 500 error code with OAuthException on successful Facebook Android SDK comment post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-comments, android-facebook

Using Facebook's Android SDK (v3.6.0) with login permission set to `publish_actions`, I am making the following simple call to post a comment to a user's feed post:

```
String userPostID = postIDParam;
String comment = commentParam;
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session.isOpened()) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("message", comment);
    Request request = new com.facebook.Request(session, userPostID + "/comments", bundle, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    //parse response data
                }
                else {
                    //handle error
                }
            }
        }
    });

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

The post goes through successfully immediately, showing up as a comment on the specified post. The bizarre part, however, is that I'm getting a `500` response code and an `OAuthException` with the error message `"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later"` in the code. I'm therefore not able to handle the successful post properly in my app.